# MultiRegional Buckets in Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I want to set a social media platform that uses buckets at multiple locations to reduce latency and enable geo-redundancy. So, what I want is to be able to determine the location of the user, identify the closest data center, save the data there, and then transfer the data to all other buckets on the server side (via a google cloud function). On the [Firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/), it says "Cloud Storage uses the same Google Cloud Storage bucket as the default Google App Engine app", but what I can't find is the default storage class of the bucket. On the [google cloud platform site](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage), it only mentions that buckets have default classes that can be changed later.

So I'm guessing when I initialize my FirebaseStoage object, I'd do so by calling:

```
FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://us")
```

to set the bucket location to the multi-regional US option? Also when a user uploads a file to storage, does the closest data center get picked automatically?

Comment: I'm also interested in this :)